# MCU input pin protection

Tags: circuit-design, circuit-protection

I want to use an MCU with some push buttons. There are long wires (6 meters) between the MCU input and the buttons. The wires are a normal pair, not twisted, not coaxial, etc. The problem is that there's is an a 30 years old boiler close to the wires, it has a high voltage transformer, which sparks and sparks a lot before it fires up the gas. What is more, these high voltage wires are unshielded. So from an EMI point of view it is a disaster.

I have put together a circuit in Eagle that I hope will eliminate this problem, protect my MCU and filters out the noise. Can you look at it and see if you think it's good, or if it needs something else? The time constant of the RC filter is 10 ms, I think it is not bad for a push button control, you don't have to press it for a disturbingly long time to charge/discharge the capacitor and of course has a low cutoff frequency. Is it necessary to change this circuit? If so, how? Replacing the wires is not an option.

[image]

Comment: Difficult to say if the filtering is good enough because we don't know how much noise is getting coupled on the line. Why don't you build the filter on a breadboard and check the output with an oscilloscope?

Comment: Is that a 2.7V zener or some other diode? What type? What's your MCU IO voltage, 5V, 3.3V, or something else?

Comment: 2.7V zener, BZV55C2V7. MCU IO voltage is 2.5V.

Comment: Is a ferrite bead or TVS diode necessary? If yes, what type?

Comment: Is there something special about these 6 meter long wires that prevents replacing them with something that doesn't pick up the noise? (as you mentioned in your question, coax and twisted pair are good options)

Comment: Other options might include making changes to the pushbutton end, adding a microcontroller that can speak a digital protocol (with error correction / redundancy).

Comment: Using the internal pullup is rather questionable. The current is very low. An external pullup (obviously on the other side of R4) would be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your circuit is probably fine.  Note that low voltage zeners do not do what you expect them to: the curve is very soft, so the leakage current is very high (this loads the MCU's pull-up) and the peak clamping voltage is very high (it's rated 2.7V only at the test current; at a peak current of some amperes as we would expect from EFT or ESD, it might be >10V).

A better solution is to use a proper ESD or surge diode, either a zener type TVS, or a snapback diode type.

Zener type TVS are available down to 5V or so.  There are some 3.3V parts, but again due to the low-voltage zener effect, they literally don't perform any better under surge conditions than 5V parts do.

Snapback diodes, like Semtech uClamp3301D, use a different technology, which offers much lower voltage ratings, with corresponding low clamping voltages under surge conditions.

Another option would be using clamp diodes, such as BAT54S, BAV99 or 2 x 1N4148W, etc., from GND to signal to VCC.  Place a large (1µF+) bypass from VCC to GND near the diode(s).  This shunts ESD to the capacitor and supply; the total supply capacitance must be several µF to keep the voltage from rising dangerously.  A single TVS on the supply affords clamping for longer duration (surge or cross-wiring) pulses.

Clamp diodes plus TVS arrays are widely available as well, e.g. Diodes Inc. D1213A-04S-7 which combines four clamp-diode pairs with a common supply TVS.

I would also use a smaller capacitor for filtering, to get better debouncing response; the 50kΩ pull-up into 10µF gives a 500ms time constant, painfully slow for human interface purposes; 0.47µF would be fine though.  (Additional debouncing can -- and should -- be done digitally in software.)

If this is just, say, an on/off toggle button that never needs to be pressed often, this can be ignored.

---

The above protects the MCU pin itself.

More importantly though, by allowing long wires (in a potentially hazardous environment*) to enter your board, you are also allowing that energy to flow into the board's ground plane (the layout has a plane, right?).

*But is this your assumption, or has it been verified e.g. with an oscilloscope and long wire antenna?  To be clear, these considerations are a good idea regardless of the environment: sooner or later, something equivalent will happen, such as people shuffling around generating static electricity and ESD, inducing pulses on the line by proximity, or by zapping the button directly.

What the board does with that energy, is the important part.  Best is to use a solid ground plane, with connectors arranged around the periphery, so that high-frequency noise and ESD currents can flow between connectors, around the edge of the board (high frequencies prefer edges), while the electronics reside safely in the middle of the board, isolated from connectors with adequate filtering and protection circuits (such as above).

Note that a 4-layer board may not be required; but a 2-layer board must be done carefully to maintain ground integrity across it.  Components and traces placed on one layer, with ground filling the other, is a safe method, but has very limited options (you can't make any crossings without disturbing the bottom side ground!).  Most likely you will need multiple traces crossing on top and bottom; realize each trace creates a hole in the respective ground fill, and overlapping traces create a hole entirely through both layers.  Add GND stitching vias periodically around each trace/bus, and several (3 or 4) where buses cross.  Prefer to cross at right angles, and minimize the overlap area (maximize ground fill).  Components and traces should almost always be above or below a ground plane, and that plane should always be connected through a short loop into neighboring plane copper.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! I will replace the Zener with a Semtech uClamp3301D. About the filter capacitor: R4 and C6 give a time constant of 10 ms, so when the user pushes the button, MCU pin will be grounded almost immediately, so it can be detected without the user having to keep it pressed.

Comment: Yes, after releasing, the pull-up resistor and C6 have a 500 ms time constant, but it is not really an issue: it is actually an "on" button, and activates a long (several minutes) countdown in the MCU, so even if it takes seconds for the resistor to pull up the voltage, it does not affect functionality or user experience. The falling edge needs to be detected relatively fast to prevent the necessity of keeping the button pressed.

Comment: "But is this your assumption, or has it been verified e.g. with an oscilloscope and long wire antenna?"
Actually there was an other circuit close previously which used an LCD display on 20 cm wires. At the moment of sparking, often strange characteres appeared on the display. So definitely there is an EMI issue here. And those were only 20 cm wires, here we have 6 m now.

I will design the PCB based on your advices (ground plane, etc), thank you for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a optocoupler (like the PC817) for decoupling the signal from the button into the I/O-pin of the controller. The voltage peak can only go through the OPV diode and can not harm the microcontroller.

You can make the resistor value for the diode relatively high, so that the diode do not get damaged. It is useful to have a ordinary diode in antiparallel to the IR-diode of the optocoupler to protect it from a negative current.

You simply pull down the MCU voltage with the optocoupler-transistor.

But you need the voltage for the optocoupler diode.

- I use the 5V voltage of my raspberry pi, but let the 5V flow into a capacitor (on a second PCB) over a diode, so that the capacitor has 5V-0.7V = 4.3V and from there a 10k Ohm resistor goes to the button.
- If there is a voltage peak on the 4.3V rail, then the current can go into the 470µF capacitor or if the current is negative, over a diode from GND to the 4.3V rail.

I have an example for my RPi Doorbell.

Circuit Image -> [RaspBerryPi doorbell protection](https://micropower.lima-city.de/stackexchange/RPI_Klingel_Entkopplung.png).

(In your case you have to use 2.5V instead of the 3.3V in the schematic.)

Comment: Opto is great for isolation, but how does the button receive power unless through a wired connection? If you just mean to use an opto common-ground, that's equivalent to a transistor, or none at all, and the series resistor is much much cheaper than the opto.

Comment: Look at the picture in the Raspi Protection circuit.

Comment: I think the circuit complexity and cost is pretty high for just a pushbutton. I don't think the opto is necessary, it is not even used for isolation. The LED current through 10k resistor is barely enough.

Comment: This is working fine. There is the protection of the i/o-pin and a current flow into the +5V is not possible too. The component are cheap, at all under 20 cent, this should not be the point. It is as protection of the current/voltage what can occur because of magnetic fields or indirect lightning strikes. It could be a bit better (5.6V Z-diode to limit the voltage of C1), but it is working here since 3 years.